# sql server: delete all the rows of all the tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to clear the database altogether and reset the data. What's the quickest way to do that? Or, what's the command that will delete all the rows of a table (and I'll repeat that process for all tables)?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to script and drop the tables, there are a number of ways to do this with a loop.  Here's probably the easiest:

sp_MsForEachTable 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?'

Comment: I just wanted to mention, that truncate is not possible for tables that are referenced by foreign keys. so this may not work for all tables.

Sorry, just saw that Phil Hunt already answered correctly.

Answer (score 11):

This approach will enable you to delete content from all tables, even those referenced by a foreign key constraint.  You can enhance it to make it check for the absence of foreign key constraints and do a `TRUNCATE TABLE` in those cases.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'DELETE FROM ?'
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
```

Comment: what about choosing db? just say `use X`?

Answer (score 1):

Drop the database and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server Management Studio to script the DROP and CREATE statements for the tables and then run the script.  Right click on the database and select Tasks --> Generate Scripts.  Run through the wizard (make sure to check the Script Drop option on the "Choose Script Options" step) and select all of the tables.  The script that is generated should drop all the tables and then recreate them.