# Deleting all rows from all tables for a specific Database in a SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete all rows from all tables in a SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899846/how-to-delete-all-rows-from-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database)

I want to delete all rows from all tables for a specific database in a sql server which has 10's of other databases as well.

I find this post with this query but not sure how it will work

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
```

My SQL Server name  ServerBanta and Database name is DingDong2010.

Taken from [How to delete all rows from all tables in a SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899846/how-to-delete-all-rows-from-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: (1) **create a backup of your database!!!** and then (2) try it :-) The script disables all check constraints for all tables, and then deletes all rows from all tables. I have a hunch it won't work, though - the author of this script forgot about foreign key constraints that might still be in place .....

Comment: how would it know which database I want to use to delete rows from all tables :S

Comment: Well, you have to run this script **on/in a given database** (e.g. by switching into that database in SQL Server Management Studio) - so yes - you'll need which database tables will get purged ...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115876/sql-server-delete-all-the-rows-of-all-the-tables!