# Truncate almost all the tables in a SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, truncate

I'm extremely new to SQL so please let me know if there's somewhere I can go to better answer this question for myself.

I have a database with several hundred tables in it which are populated to varying degrees. I need to truncate almost all of them for testing while retaining the data in a few for configuration.

I've seen plenty of posts on truncating *all* of them (even with foreign keys, which I have) but I'm hoping there's some jiggery pokery I can do with either some 'if' type structure. Would the best solution just be to copy out those few tables, do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116021/5071339), then copy the data back in?

Comment: you can use a tool for truncate where you can select/ unselect multiple tables like sqlyog for MySQL

Comment: i might use some query like this.. if its a one time thing.

select 'truncate '+TABLE_NAME+';' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
Where TABLE_NAME!='<your tables which you dont want to truncate>'

Comment: You should specify the target database engine. I suspect the solution will heavily depend on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you are very new to SQL, here there is a very basic script to generate the TRUNCATE queries:

```
DECLARE @ExcludedTables TABLE (TableName NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @ExcludedTables VALUES ('Table1')
INSERT INTO @ExcludedTables VALUES ('Table2')
INSERT INTO @ExcludedTables VALUES ('Table3')

SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE [' + S.[name] + '].[' + T.[name] + ']', T.*
FROM sys.tables AS T 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id 
WHERE T.[name] NOT IN (SELECT TableName FROM @ExcludedTables)
```

I made a table variable where you can insert the tables names you want to exclude. You can also use a temporary table, or even a normal table for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

limiting certain tables isn't difficult.  you can create a temporary table or table variable with their names in it.  then you can create a list of all table names in the database whose names aren't in the structure you created for your keepers.

assuming the database has foreign keys, you'll either have to truncate the tables in the correct order or disable/drop the constraints.  this is more of a headache than above, but there are probably routines available for this around.

specific details will require knowing what database system you're using (sql server, my sql, oracle, etc.)